# Run exe with pre arguments in Java

Tags: java, windows, subprocess, installutil

I want to run an exe with a pre-argument in java. For example, if this is executed in a command prompt.

```
C:\> installutil myApp.exe
```

installutil is the pre-argument (or command) to myApp.exe. Here it is different than passing normal arguments to `Runtime.getRuntime().exec()` or `Process.start()`;

Thanks.

Comment: There's no such thing as "pre-arguments" in a command prompt. `runIt` would have to be an actual command, in which case `myApp.exe` is an argument to `runIt`.

Comment: @Inerdial Please make that an answer.

Comment: But runIt is not an exe. So it gives an error when try to pass those as you said.

Comment: @PrasadMathugama Then you're missing something. `runIt` might be an executable in the current working directory of the command prompt, but not on the `PATH`, which is why your Java program won't necessarily pick it up.

Comment: What would you expect for `$ runIt myApp.exe` to produce as result ? (compared to the normal execution of myApp.exe)

Comment: well actually what I want is installutill myApp.exe. So please replace runIt by installutill which is microsoft installer tool.

Comment: myApp will not install unless use with installutil myApp. how I can achieve that with java?

Comment: @Prasad Then, where exactly are you using Java? If runit is a M$ tool, and myApp is an exe, what does Java have to do in all this?

Comment: All I want to know is can't we achieve this in java? I am pretty sure there should be a way.

Answer (score 9):

There’s no such thing as "pre-arguments" in a command prompt. `runIt` would have to be an actual command, in which case `myApp.exe` is an argument to `runIt`.

It seems the program you're trying to run is part of the .NET framework SDK which does not get put on `PATH` during installation – you’re probably using the *Visual Studio Command Prompt*. On my machine the full path is `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\InstallUtil.exe`, it will be something similar on yours, you need to start the program using this full path.

Comment: myApp will not install unless use with installutil myApp. how I can achieve that with java?

Comment: `installutil.exe` will be an executable file *somewhere*. MSDN tells me it's one of the .NET tools, so it's likely somewhere deep inside the Windows installation directory; and, more importantly, **not** on `PATH`. Find that executable, run it from Java, and pass `myApp.exe` as an argument. Use full paths to both executables.